# I'm unable to print my list using the format I specified beforehand

Tags: python

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
LAYOUT = "{!s:4} {!s:11} {!s:10} {!s:10} {!s:15} {!s:10} {!s:10} {!s:15} {!s:10} {!s:10}"
Item_1 = [002,"Cucharas",12.3,12.5,"4/5/16",200,12.5,"4/6/16",150,140]   
print LAYOUT.format("UPC", "Item", "Cost", "Price", "F_Comp", "QTY", "Profit", "F_Venta", "QTY_Sold", "QTY_Alm")
print LAYOUT.format[Item_1]
```

I want to print several lists using `LAYOUT`. I actually took this method of formatting from another answer here, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print LAYOUT.format[Item_1]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets, `[]`, are generally used for indexing and slicing, which calls the object's `__getitem__` method, which the `str.format` function does not have. Use parentheses like you did in the previous line, and unpack the iterable with `*`:

```
print LAYOUT.format(*Item_1)
```